# How to resolve Expecting code to raise a throwable unit test case for Exceptions?

Tags: java, junit, junit5

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mFhJ.png)  I am trying to write test case for such case , In this I am expecting `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`, I was trying to assert the same using assert that thrown by but I am getting assertion error as expecting code to raise a `Throwable`. How to resolve this, can someone help me with this.

I am using `JUnit5`.

As shown in screenshot the method doesn't seem to run after applying exception case

```
@Test
public void insertUpdateDatatypesizecountValidation() throws Exception {
    id = 0;
    StandAloneConnection standAloneConnection = new StandAloneConnection(
                        propertyFile);
    Connection conn = standAloneConnection.getConnection();
    assertThatThrownBy(() -> called.datas(conn, id))
            .hasMessage("Column 'ID' cannot be null")
            .isInstanceOf(SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.class);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `AssertJ` library for your issue and it will look like

```
assertThatThrownBy(() -> testingMehtod())
                .hasMessage("Checked message")
                .isInstanceOf(SQLException.class);
```

Or you can use `junit` assertions like

```
assertThrows(SQLException.class, () -> testingMehtod(), "Checked message");
```

It is important to understand reasons for using such tests. So a developer is checking does a method **throws** (or doesn't throw) an exception during execution.

**Simple example**

Suppose we have a method like

```
static void testMethod(String arg) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(arg, "Argument cannot be null");
    // some code to work
}
```

We have to check does it work properly:

```
@Test
void someTest() {
    assertThrows(NullPointerException.class,
            () -> testMethod(null),
            "Argument cannot be null");
    assertDoesNotThrow(() -> testMethod("data"));
}
```

Tests above will pass.

Tests below will fail with `AssertionError`

```
@Test
void someTest1() {
    assertThrows(IOException.class, () -> testMethod(null), "IO error");
}

@Test
void someTest2() {
    assertThrows(NullPointerException.class,
            () -> testMethod("data"),
            "Argument cannot be null");
}
```

Example above using `junit assertions`. Using `AssertJ` is quit more interesting in my mind.

Comment: I find both of these examples more readable than the accepted answer, with a preference towards the AssertJ solution even though it may require an additional library.

Comment: I am getting assertion error 
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting code to raise a throwable.
how to solve this @Gavin

Comment: @devbranch I've updated an answer for you to understand how it works. You should understand that if you are testing for an exceptions your should throw it in some situations which you are waiting for and should not throw in correct cases

Comment: @Alex , when I am adding the exception the method seems like not executed , I have attached a image in my ques , can u pls have a look and guide me regarding the same ..

Comment: @devbranch what is your code `called.datas(conn, id)` doing? Does it throw exception on  incorrect data or just returns some results in any case without exceptions?

Comment: Its throwing an exception @Alex
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'ID' cannot be null

Comment: @devbranch why do you think that your method doesn't execute? according your screenshot - 5 tests run and no failures. If you wish to see if it really works, try to change `java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` to other exception (for example `IOException`) and run test - will it fail or not

Comment: @Alex , I have changed the exception and ran its not giving any failure or pass case, same isssue which I have attached no changes , I have attached new screenshot pls have a look

Comment: @devbranch you should check if test executes to `assertThatThrownBy` in your code. You can do it in debug mode or just add `System.out.println` or log after getting a connection

Answer (score 3):

you can use :

```
Assertions.assertThrows(DataTruncation.class, new Executable() {
    @Override
    public void execute() throws Throwable {
        //the code which you expect to throw this exception
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Not completely sure of what your question is... but as i understood you're trying to check the type of exception... so in such case you can use this
assertTrue( exception instanceOf DataTruncationException)

is that what you meant for?
You can add a try catch block and then assert it in the catch block

```
try {
functionToCall()
} catch (Throwable ex) {
assertTrue(ex instanceof DataTruncationException)
}
```

Comment: can u pls share a sample code for the same @Inferno , If you dont mind

Comment: try {
            <your function call here>
        } catch (Throwable ex){
            assertTrue(ex instanceof DataTruncationException);
        }

Comment: This example is incomplete. It doesn't fail the test when functionToCall() does not throw an exception.

Comment: Right @StefanBirkner , can u suggest some better way to write it